# How do I listen to changes in Firebase custom claims?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app in Ionic Vue with Firebase as my backend.
I am using Firebase custom claims to assign user roles ('paid user' or 'free user') and I have set up a cloud function that assign the roles without any problems.

Now I want my app to be able to listen to changes in the custom claims, so that if a free user becomes a paid user, the app will know in realtime. Current I only get the updated custom claim if I reload the app by using onAuthStateChanged like this:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, () => {
  if (auth.currentUser) {
    auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult(true).then((idTokenResult) => {
      console.log(idTokenResult);
      auth.currentUser.subscriber = idTokenResult.claims.subscriber;
    });
  }
// Run app
});
```

What would be the best approach to listen for changes when the user gets assigned a new role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want my app to be able to listen to changes in the custom claims

This is not possible with the Fireabse Authentication service. You should implement your own mechanism: For example, having a Firestore document per user and save the user's role in this document. This way you can [set a realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9) to the user's Firestore document and be alerted in your front end that the user's role has changed.

Note that this will only implement an alerting system. You'll still have to refresh the token with `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()` (as shown in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client)) in order to reflect the new role in your front-end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Renaud.
Would the best approach be to set up a realtime listener through Vuex or Pinia and then use it on every page where I need to listen for changes?

Comment: Setting the Firestore listener in your store is indeed one of the possible options.

Comment: Isn't there `Firebase Realtime Database` and then set up `Realtime Database triggers` for this purpose? I will need a similar thing that's why I am asking...

Comment: @SinisaM if you have a question which is not fully related to this Q&A I suggest to create a new Question in SO.